# How to set a NSUserDefault to the last index in an array the user pressed (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to make an app that will display a array of items which the user clicks a button to go through. When the user exits the app I would like the app to save the in the last thing the user pressed. So far I have tried to set NSUserDefaults but I have been unsuccessful thus far.
Code in Swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var TechByteLabel: UILabel!
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var TechfactIndex = 0
let TechnologyfactBook = TechFactBook()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    TechByteLabel.text =  TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray[TechfactIndex]
    defaults.setObject(TechfactIndex, forKey: "ByteLocation")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

@IBAction func showFunFact() {

    TechfactIndex++
    if (TechfactIndex >= TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray.count) {
        self.TechfactIndex = 0
    }
    TechByteLabel.text = TechnologyfactBook.TechfactsArray[TechfactIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give you the same advice I gave this guy in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351805/3149796

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the last value from the "TechfactsArray", then you can do it via using the property:

```
defaults.setObject(TechfactsArray.last, forKey: "LastValue")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope that code below will helps!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load your settings from NSUserDefault
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    // Save new settings to NSUserDefault
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the defaults value in `viewDidLoad` and set it in `showFunFact()`.

The functions to do that would be:

```
// viewDidLoad:
TechfactIndex = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("ByteLocation")

// showFunFact
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(TechfactIndex, forKey: "ByteLocation")
```